# CSS3 Media Queries are not working

Tags: html, css, mobile-website, media-queries

I've recently been developing a mobile version for a website, and quite simply want to be able to change the CSS file if the browser is detected to be on a mobile device. You can view my previous attempts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582182/switching-stylesheet-with-javascript-based-on-browser), but I have now decided that the most feasible way of getting this done is to focus on Media Queries.

The problem I have here is that the media queries just don't work at all. It always loads the default stylesheet. Here is the code I have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<link href="../css/style.css" id="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="../css/style_mob.css" />
```

Have I missed something with this code? I've tried using the many tutorials offered for this but none seem to help me. I've really hit a dead end here so any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default stylesheet doesn't have any attributes that would stop it from being loaded.

You could give it `media="screen and (min-width: 481px)"`, but that would lead to the danger, that older browsers won't load it either.

Usually it's best, to have the default stylesheet load and just make sure, that the mobile stylesheet overrides anything you don't need from the default stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That certainly helps. The problem is here is that the default CSS file is very large so I would have to go through every style and bascially override it to strip it out. The mobile style sheet doesn't have a lot of style elements, hence why I decided to just make one from scratch. I suppose if I have to just ovveride everything to default that would just have to do!

Comment: You could test older browsers using the media query for the default stylesheet. Most will load it because it starts with `screen`. If you find a specific browser that doesn't load it, but you have to support, there may be alternatives.

Comment: I appear to be close to a working solution thanks to your help. I have a query though. I've had to use some CSS conditionals to ensure that a stylesheet is loaded with IE browsers. This raises the question as to how this page would render for, say, older versions of Firefox which do not support CSS3.

Comment: That's impossible to say generally. Best would be to create a version of your stylesheet with all CSS 3 specific properites removed and see if your site still works with it.

Comment: I don't think I've explained myself well enough, sorry RoToRa. What I mean is that the code used to detect a mobile device (the code above in your answer) is generally a CSS3 feature is it not? So this raises the question, if older Firefox or Chrome browsers which do not support CSS3 are used to render these pages, no stylesheet will be loaded. This is a general query, I'm going to mark this question answered as the general query has in fact been correctly answered, thank you!

Comment: As far as I know, most older browsers, will recognize the `screen` part of the media query, and will ignore the rest it doesn't know and load the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Completing the conditional with `min-device-width` worked for me on iOS. Note the word device. It did work fine on android even without the word device, however.

Answer (score 1):

i used bootstrap in a press site but it does not worked on IE8, i used css3-mediaqueries.js javascript but still not working. if you want your media query to work with this javascript file add screen to your media query line in css

here is an example :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>

<style>
     @media screen and (max-width:900px) {}
     @media screen and (min-width:900px) and (max-width:1200px) {}
     @media screen and (min-width:1200px) {}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
```

css Link line as simple as above line.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `initial-scale=1.0` and `maximum-scale=1.0`, then it's a bit redundant to have `user-scalable=0` as well. Having maximum-scale set to equal initial-scale means the user can't zoom in at all because they start at the maximum zoom.